# Xamarin Forms: How to show a full screen page when selecting a specific tab

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have a tabbed main application with Xamarin Forms.

I am looking to open a Content page in full screen (without tabs and titles) when switching to a specific tab.
I am able to obtain the desired behaviour when I press a button like this:

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DashboardPage());
```

Though i'm not sure how to make it to automatically open when switching to that specific tab.

Any help will be so much appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: that really goes against common UI standards for a tabbed page

Comment: This seems like a bad design. For instance, a tab is a tab and you seem to be mixing and matching design concepts. However, there doesn't seem to be anything in the tabbed page class you can easily override. so you would likely need to implement a renderer if possible, my vote is to rethink your design a little

Comment: I am quite new to this, I basically need one page to be full screen and at the same time to have others tabbed (like various settings, stats, ... ). Any suggestion on what would be a better approach?
Basically, I am trying to imitate the behaviour in WhatsApp on Android: when you go to the camera tab it opens full-screen right? Are they allowed to go against rules?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to obtain it by adding the following to the tab page class:

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DashboardPage());
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        // move on a different tab to avoid infinite loop when back button is pressed
        var masterPage = this.Parent as TabbedPage;
        masterPage.CurrentPage = masterPage.Children[0];
    }
```

Probably not the most elegant way but it does the job